# Override field name deserialization in ServiceStack

Tags: serialization, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack to deserialize some HTML form values but can't figure out how to override the value that each field should be read from.

For example, the form posts a value to `first_name` but the property on my POCO is called `FirstName`. how would I do mapping like that in ServiceStack

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The ServiceStack Text serializers support [DataMember] aliases where you can use the Name parameter to specify what alias each field should be, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name="first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Note: Once you add [DataContract] / [DataMember] attributes to your DTOs then the behavior becomes opt-in and you will have add [DataMember] on each of the properties you want serialized.

#### Emitting idiomatic JSON for all DTOs

You can instruct JSON serialization to follow a different convention by specifying the following global settings:

```
//Emit {"firstName":"first","lastName":"last"}
JsConfig.Init(new Config { TextCase = TextCase.CamelCase });

//Emit {"first_name":"first","last_name":"last"}
JsConfig.Init(new Config { TextCase = TextCase.SnakeCase });
```

Comment: I've tried that and I don't see that opt-in behaviour either, it seems like service stack completely ignores the DataContract/Member Attribute. I'm using the attributes in System.Runtime.Serialization.

Comment: Ok this works for ServiceStack's JSON and JSV text serializers, I've just commited the change where the above also works for the QueryString and HTML Form POST parsing routine at:  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e1d48d9d7e9e17c506e3759bfd0712cbad58280d - available on next release of ServiceStack  on NuGet in a few days. You can use JSON or Request model binder in the meantime https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization

Comment: Is [DataContract] still the only way to customize the Property Name? As its not optimal when applying on a Base class, in a POCO env.

Comment: @mythz - The [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) says, "At the moment it is not possible to customize the Property Name."  May I assume that line in the documentation is out of date?

Answer (score 5):

In order to serialise C# class with underscore convention, you need to set JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames to true as [mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) said.

```
JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true;
```

But, in my experience, Deserialising would fail, as it expect CamelCased values. To enable underscore json value deserialisation, you need to set JsConfig's PropertyConvention.

```
JsConfig.PropertyConvention = PropertyConvention.Lenient;
```

I use a simple helper method to resolve the serialisation and deserialisation issue.

```
public static class JsonHelpers
{
    public static string ToUnderscoredJson<T>(this T obj)
    {
        JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true;

        return JsConfig.PreferInterfaces
            ? JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(obj, AssemblyUtils.MainInterface<T>())
            : JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(obj);
    }

    public static T FromUnderscoredJson<T>(this string json)
    {
        JsConfig.PropertyConvention = PropertyConvention.Lenient;
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<T>(json);
    }
}
```